# Copy and paste data data from another sheet and autofill based on another column

Tags: vba, excel

I have data to copy from sheet 1 ("Invoice") to sheet 2 ("Inventory"). I only need to copy 1 cell consist of numbers of Invoice ("1,2,3,etc").
I already succeed copy (Invoice.D14) and paste the cells (Inventory.B4) however i need to autofill as far as another column (Inventory.D4) in sheet 2 ("Inventory"). Please see my code as follow :

```
Dim Outgoing As Worksheet
Dim Invoice As Worksheet

Set Outgoing = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Inventory")
Set Invoice = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Invoice")


    Invoice.Range("D14").Copy
    Outgoing.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).Range("B1").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial

With Range("B4").Resize(4)
        .Value = [B4]
        .AutoFill .Resize(Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1)

End With
```

It keeps coming with error message.
Anyone can help?

**EDIT MESSAGE**

I already copied from sheet 1 ("Invoice") to sheet 2 ("Inventory"). 
On sheet 1 ("Invoice") contains :

1. Data code with range from B21 until B27
2. Transaction ID with cell D14

I copy above data to sheet 2 ("Inventory") with detail :

1. Data code copy to Inventory.columnD (start row at 4)
2. Transaction ID copy to inventory.columnB (start row at 4)

If i input 3 code on data code it will copy to Inventory with 3 code as well (3 rows), however since i only copy 1 cell for transaction ID the output on Inventory only 1 cell as well.

What i need is to autofill the transaction ID as long as data code that i input previously. However, if i'm using autofill i don't know why it's always shown error message. So i try a different way, to copy the first transaction ID.

I try below code as well :

```
Sub Outgoing_Data()

 Dim Inventory As Worksheet
 Dim Invoice As Worksheet
 Dim columnB As Range
 Dim columnD As Range
 Dim c As Range
 Dim i As Long
 Dim lastNonEmptyRow As Range

Set Outgoing = Worksheets("Inventory")
Set Invoice = Worksheets("Invoice")
Set columnB = Range("B:B")
Set columnD = Range("D:D")


    Invoice.Range("B21:B27").Copy
    Outgoing.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).Range("D1").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial

    Invoice.Range("D14").Copy
    Outgoing.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).Range("B1").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial

    i = 5
    Set lastNonEmptyRow = Outgoing.Range(Cells(i - 1, 2), Cells(i - 1, 2))
    For Each c In columnD.Cells
        If c.Value2 = "" Then Exit For
        i = i + 1
    Next c

    Do While columnD(i) <> ""
        lastNonEmptyRow.Copy Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 2)).PasteSpecial
    i = i + 1
Loop


End Sub
```

The output that i want it :
| transaction_ID | Product ID

---

| 1              |  2DFGH4
| 1              |  2DFGH7
| 1              |  2HJTY0
| 2              |  1JKTY7
| 2              |  5THSD1
| 3              |  4GHTY9

(Have no idea how to draw a table in here, but hope you understand what i'm saying)
The result, transaction ID already as long as data code. For the first trial it looks fine. But when i change the transaction ID on Invoice and run it again without delete the data on Inventory, the transaction ID on Inventory only copy on 1 cell. Is there any suggestion for this?

Really appreciate your answers.
Thank you

Comment: why are you useing `PasteSpecial` ? do you need to paste only the values ? formats ? maybe you can use the regular paste method ?

Comment: The `Paste` method doesn't work in inactive sheet. `PasteSpecial` is imho much better solution, if you don't want to cut something.

Comment: @ShaiRado, limak already reply your answer. It's true, i can't use regular paste (.paste) since it will be shown debug.

Comment: @Limak how did you get to this conclusion  ? you can easily copy paste with the following lone of code `Invoice.Range("D14").Copy Outgoing.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).Range("B1").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)`

Comment: ShaiRado, try this tree lines `Sheets("Sheet1").Select`
`Range("B4").Copy`
`Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B4").Paste`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the wrong sheet is activated? Try:

```
With Outgoing.Range("B4").Resize(4)
        .Value = [B4]
        .AutoFill .Resize(Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1)
End With
```

**EDIT:**

The problem with `.AutoFill .Resize(Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1)` is that `Rows.Count` returns absolute value of rows, counting form 1, not 4 (which is the row that you are refering to). So, if you always start autofill form B4, simple -3 will work fro you:

```
.AutoFill .Resize(Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 3)
```

But, if this row would change dynamically, you can add this to row calculation, for example:

```
expectedRow = 8
    With Outgoing.Range("B" & expectedRow).Resize(4)
            .Value = Range("B" & expectedRow).Value
            .AutoFill .Resize(Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - expectedRow + 1)
    End With
```

By the way, I don't uderstand the purpose of this `.Value = Range("B" & expectedRow).Value` line and `Resize(4)` part of `With` command, but I don't know how your data looks like and what is your particular goal, so try to remove this and see if output works out for you.

Comment: hi, @limak it's work. However still auto fill more than i expected.

Comment: For example, i input 3 data in Column "C". The autofill appear 5 rows. Already try .rows+1, the data appear 6 rows. Try offset(1,0) as well and still not working as well. Is there anything wrong? For your info, I used header.

Comment: @LiaEngeline, I think your question isn't very clear. You may want to add details about actual input and output scenarios, BTW you may want to try the solution I posted, too

Comment: @Lia Engeline, I have edited my post, check this out.

Comment: hi @Limak, I try the code. And it's not working, the result still same with my code. Btw, already edit my message. Hope you can more understand what i meant.

Comment: @Lia Engeline, first of all, remove form `Outgoing.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).Range("D1").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial` (and similar line below) `Cells(Rows.Count, 1).` or `Range("D1").`, because this two commands are canceling each others out. Second, you don't have to draw any table, just upload some small part of screenshot, showing the data and expected result.

Comment: Third, your second approach, avoiding autofill should be much better. However, this is another question, so please create another threat, showing only this new approach, to avoid mess.

Answer (score 0):

your aim is not very clear

try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim Outgoing As Worksheet
    Dim Invoice As Worksheet

    Set Outgoing = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Inventory")
    Set Invoice = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Invoice")

    Invoice.Range("D14").Copy
    With Outgoing
        With .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).Range("B1").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            .PasteSpecial
            .Resize(4).Value = .Value
            .Resize(4).AutoFill .Resize(4, 2)
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @LiaEngeline, I'd like to know whether this would have worked for you and, if not, why. Thank you

Comment: hi  I try the code. And it's not working since your code copy the value on B column into C Column. And the length of autofill more than the product ID on Column D. However, I already edit my question. Hope it clears you more.